# How do I get an element to always occupy a specific percentage of its parent element, even when the browser is resized?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

**Note:  I know that `elem {height: 90%}` exists.**

What I need:

- an element to occupy x% width and y% height of its parent element, regardless of size
- the parent has margins and padding

My problem:

- it looks great at first, but when I make the browser window smaller, content starts spilling out of the bottom of the parent.  **This is super depressing.**  It looks to me like the size of the `#load` div is 90% of its parent *(as requested; see stylesheet below)*; unfortunately this 90% doesn't take margins or padding into account.  **What is going on here?** If the answer is just that percentages don't work "like that" when there are margins/padding, **how do I specify that an element occupies x percent of its parent after deducting margins/padding?**  Also, note that jQueryui uses css that I would like to avoid touching, if possible.

My markup:

```
<div id="tabscontainer">
      <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#create">Create</a></li>
            <li><a href="#load">Load</a></li>
        </ul>
 <div id="create">
something or other
 </div>
 <div id="load">
... there is a lot of content here ...
 </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {$("#tabs").tabs();});

</script>
```

My styling:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#tabscontainer {
    height: 95%;
}

#tabs {
    height: 100%;
}

#tabs > div {
    height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Also, the default jQuery styling of tabs is in effect (with no changes from me).

Comment: For all I know, the problem is that styles are being inherited, as in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877636/in-html-how-is-a-child-elements-percentage-based-size-calculated-when-its-pare

Comment: Where are you setting those margins and paddings and how?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. I think the problem is that the styles from jQuery UI is in PX while the rest is in %. You usually run into problems when you combine that. Try setting margins, paddings and borders in % (I know you don't want to mess with jQuery CSS, but you can override it with !important or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the styles from jQuery UI are in PX while the rest are in %. You usually run into problems when you combine that. Try setting margins, paddings and borders in % (I know you don't want to mess with jQuery CSS, but you can override it with !important or similar).

Comment: Comment to update and correct myself: 
1: Borders can't be set to % (I don't remember if you used them or not, but just FYI).
2: Another option you have is to use the box-sizing model (though you'd lose support for IE prior to version 8). Take a look at this article:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/ (there is one section called precisely Percentage + Padding + Border = Trouble)

Answer (score 0):

I find that when `height` doesn't cut it, putting `position:relative;` on the parent and `position:absolute;` on the child will prove more reliable. Then of course `top:5%; right:5%; bottom:5%; left:5%;`. This should ignore the padding.

Not sure if that'll work with your existing styles though.